# Quantum particle in the real projective plane $\mathbb{RP}^2$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, boundary-conditions

Consider particles living in a $2D$ space with boundary conditions such that the space takes up a finite area. During introductory quantum mechanics classes, we are exposed to many examples, which I list for comparison:

Particle in a square box: The relevant eigenfunctions of the Laplacian in Cartesian coordinates are $\sin(m \pi x/L)\sin(n \pi y/L)$ and are designed to vanish at the boundaries; i.e. $m,n\in\mathbb{N}^+$.

Particle on a torus / square box with periodic boundary conditions: The eigenfunctions are $e^{2m\pi i x/L}e^{2n\pi i y/L}$ and are designed so the wavefunction is periodic at the boundaries, i.e. $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Particle on a sphere: The eigenfunctions of the Laplacian restricted to the sphere are spherical harmonics, $Y_{lm}(\theta, \phi)$.

Particle in a circular box or disk: The relevant eigenfunctions are $J_m(a_{mn}r/R) e^{im\theta}$, where $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ ensures periodicity in $\theta$ of the wavefunction, and $J_m$ is a Bessel function with $J_m{a_{mn}} =0$ to ensure vanishing at the wall.

Particle in the real projective plane of $\mathbb{RP}^2$: ???

---

By real projective plane, I have in mind the disk with antipodal points identified. It is sort of a natural periodic-boundary-condition version of the disk. For example, I have drawn below part of some particle's trajectory that leaves $A$ pointing to the left, reaches $B$, pops out at the identified antipodal point and continues on its way to $C$. The full trajectory will loop back to $A$. That is, it is straightforward to draw the classical paths of a particle in $\mathbb{RP}^2$:

[image: Straight line in the real projective plane]

Because classical mechanics appears to be straightforward on $\mathbb{RP}^2$, I expect that Feynman path integral quantum mechanics will allow us to write down the propagator, by which I mean we can in principle use path integrals to find the matrix elements of the time-evolution operator. However, I would instead like to describe the time evolution by finding the eigenvectors of the Laplacian that satisfy the $\mathbb{RP}^2$ boundary conditions, similar to how an introductory quantum mechanics class would find the eigenfunctions of the systems described at the top.

---

**My question is:** How do I implement the boundary conditions of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ to find eigenfunctions of the free particle Hamiltonian (i.e. the Laplacian) satisfying the boundary conditions? What are these boundary-condition-satisfying eigenfunctions?

---

My thoughts: I guess that polar coordinates will be useful, where the boundary conditions are that I want the wavefunction $\psi(r,\theta)=\psi(r,\theta+2\pi)$, and I additionally want $\psi(r=R,\theta)=\psi(r=R,\theta+\pi)$. I think that separation of variables and the first boundary condition will lead again to having an $e^{im\theta}$ piece with $m\in\mathbb{Z}$, but the oddness-evenness of $m$ will enforce different conditions on the radial piece of the wavefunction. Probably for odd $m$ in the $e^{im\theta}$ piece, I'll need to enforce vanishing at $r=R$, while for even $m$ I'll need have the partial derivative of $\psi$ with respect to $r$ vanish at $r=R$ to prevent cusps (as that would give delta-functions on taking the second derivative). Is this correct?

Comment: Related, on Math SE: [Laplacian on Projective plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3162146)

Comment: The projective plane has no inherent metrical (distance) structure. The metric structure is crucial here because a particle that is moving in a projective plane where the "line at infinity" is literally at infinite distance is a different beast from a projective plane that is an elliptic plane with finite size. For one, the infinitely large plane cannot have its edges reached in finite time by a moving particle, but the finite one can.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer I agree. For this problem, I'm considering a flat metric exemplified by my picture of a classical geodesic (straight line free particle trajectory), where the radius of the disk is finite.

Comment: As a note here, unrelated to my question with the flat metric, I believe that replacing the disk with a hemisphere (the usual metric on the hemisphere) will lead to spherical harmonics where only even $l$ are allowed.